# every object should have at least one true property value in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i want to create a function to return true (each object should have at least one `isValid:true`) else return false.

```js
const Items = [{
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: true
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  },
  {
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: true
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  }
]

// i tried : 
validateSection() {
  Items.map(item => {
    if (item.parentValidators) {
      const logs = item.parentValidators;
      return logs.map(l => {
        return l.isValid ? true : l.isValid;
      });
    }
  }).map((i, indx, arr) => {
    let count = 0;
    if (i.includes('true')) {
      count++;
    }
    return count === array.length ? true : false;
  })

}
```

Answer (score 4):

A function to return true if every item in `Items` has at least one validator with an `isValid` value of `true` is the perfect use case for a combination of the array `every` and `some` methods:

```js
const Items = [{
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: true
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  },
  {
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: true
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  }
]

// i tried : 
function validateSection() {
  return Items.every(validators => validators.parentValidators.some(i => i.isValid));
}

console.log(validateSection())
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const Items = [{
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: true
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  },
  {
    parentValidators: [{
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }, {
      isValid: false
    }]
  }
]

const res = Items.map(({parentValidators:v})=> v.some(({isValid:i})=>i))

console.log(res)
```